# On Check-in, how do I detect a new file

Tags: wss-3.0, event-handlers

Right now I have a SPItemEventReceiver that overrides ItemCheckedIn.  It checks out the file, creates/marks a hidden field, and checks it back in. The reason for setting a property on the file is to prevent the process from changing the item again; it modifies permissions of the item.

This works, but has some side-effects.  The alerts don't work properly due to the Alert system detecting System modifications and the item/file's "Modified By" field gets set to System Account.

Some options include,

1. Fix/work-around the side effects
2. Put the data somewhere else

   - put the data in web.Properties
   - create a list in which to put the data
3. Find a way to tweak the Item properties before the initial check-in
4. Find a way to detect the a file is new right after it is checked in.

I know how to do 2 and might accomplish 1, but I've struggled finding a way to do 3 or 4.

Update:  Versioning is not on, but Checkout is required.

Comment: Do you have versioning turned on?

Answer (score 4):

I would try using [SPListList.SystemUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx) in the event handler. I suspect that you're using SPListItem.Update() at the moment. SystemUpdate() won't change the modified date or user.

Comment: I did not realize that was a side-effect of using SystemUpdate.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I come across that one in nearly every project...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that merge 3 & 4.

1. In ItemCheckingIn, add a property to the changed properties list.       `properties.AfterProperties.ChangedProperties.Add(FieldName, value)`
2. In ItemCheckedIn, you can check the property of the item, which will get the value set in ChangedProperties. `var s = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem[FieldName]);`

So, to that takes care of setting a value without checking-out/in.  the value in this case is a timestamp, which I can detect if it is old or not. If the current time is within a few seconds of the timestamp, then I know the file is new.